# How does transistor amplify current?

Tags: transistors, current, amplifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I don't care how a transistor works, how do I get one to work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5336/i-dont-care-how-a-transistor-works-how-do-i-get-one-to-work)
>   [Basic questions about transistor amplification](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24591/basic-questions-about-transistor-amplification)

I have heard transistors are used in many electronic devices to amplify current such as in microphones which amplify the sound. I want to know how do they what do they do? How can a transistor just amplify electric current from nothing?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked previously. This one should be closed.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24591/basic-questions-about-transistor-amplification

Answer (score 1):

Transistor needs a power source, it can't amplify a signal "from nothing".

You ask the very basics. I think you should read the first chapter of some book.
For example [Principles of Transistor Circuits](http://books.google.com/books?id=mfec2Zw_b7wC&printsec=frontcover&dq=principles+of+transistor+circuits&hl=cs&sa=X&ei=exkkT8ulOYyVOpOjgcwI&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=principles%20of%20transistor%20circuits&f=false).

Or at least [Wikipedia article on transistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor).